# Maintaining DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE between local and production environments

Tags: docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

Running into an issue when we deployed to production, had to update manage.py to set `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")` to `config.settings.production`. Of course this broke local settings when we pulled back to our dev branch.

We're running our containers via the `docker-compose local.yml` commands recommended in the documentation.

Am I missing something? Is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This environment variable should be set via a `.env` file, the production one is located under [`.envs/.production/.django`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/.envs/.production/.django#L4), and is not in source control (for security reasons). So yes, it is by design.

Depending on how you start your server, this file might be missing and the environment will end up unset.

Comment: Thanks, I did some testing and looks like everything is normal. Not sure what the issue was during our initial deployment.